# What algorithm is most suitable for large text compression?

Tags: data-compression

Currently, I am looking for an lossless compression algorithm that is suitable for a large amount of text, that will be further encrypt by AES and use as the payload in steganography.

Based on [A Comparative Study Of Text Compression Algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265661965_A_Comparative_Study_Of_Text_Compression_Algorithms), it seems that Arithmetic coding is preferable in Statistical compression techniques, while LZB is recommended for Dictionary compression techniques.

So now I am wondering whether Statistical compression or Dictionary compression is more suitable for large English text compression in terms of compression ratio and ease-to-implement.

I have search through but still barely have an idea of the suitable algorithm. Thank you very much for your time in answering. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Conspicuous in its absence in the survey is [BWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-text-compression-algorithm

Comment: There are several aspects to consider, for example compression rate, speed of compression, speed of decompression, availability. All of these could depend on the size and nature of text being compressed. Any specific application will be interested in a particular tradeoff. Only you know what will work best for you. The easiest way to go is to pick some standard algorithms which are already implemented in libraries or applications and compare them empirically on your texts, considering all the measures of performance mentioned above.

Comment: If there was a single "best algorithm", we'd all be using it already. What is best will depend very much on the specifics of your use case. Why can't you try a few and see what works best?

Comment: First compress, then cypher. Cyphering the data will get rid of regularities (if your cypher is at all good), and regularities is what compression exploits.

Comment: Lossless compression is limited by the entropy of the text. If I am right, the compression factor is not huge, just a few units.

Answer (score -2):

The Linux kernel has a huge source code, with about 3.2 million lines of code. Source code is totally text, so this can give you an idea about the level of compression that is possible. The entire source code is distributed as a .tar.xz file. Its size is close to 110 megabytes. This offers great compression. Decompress it and see the difference in file size!

Comment: This sheds no light on the relative merits of *Statistical compression* vs. *Dictionary compression* as per *C. Ying*'s question.

Comment: 110 MB for 3.2 million lines makes lines of 34 bytes on average (my personal average is consistently 22 characters per line, including blanks). How do you conclude that the compression is "great" ?